# Cos'è la "collamidina"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Pane e tempesta* di Stefano Benni ho letto questa frase:

> La sorella di Carmela, Marcella la cartolaia, sexy e odorosa di quaderni freschi e **collamidina**.

Non so cos'è la "collamidina", ma dal contesto immagino fosse qualche prodotto di cartoleria. Non ho trovato il significato di questo vocabolo in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato e neanche in altri siti web. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La ***collamidina*** era un prodotto di cartoleria, una colla in pasta dal caratteristico odore di mandorla utilizzata negli anni '30 e '40, ad esempio, come collante per le figurine dei calciatori.

Da [Saltatempo di Stefano Benni](https://books.google.it/books?id=-g8gCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&lpg=PT65&dq=collamidina&source=bl&ots=dPgZZKWqnB&sig=k8cnRkOSr5uRbmRNY3615-Duiz4&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8sJ670rDWAhUSmbQKHc6jBAwQ6AEIVzAL#v=onepage&q=collamidina&f=false):

> Una volta che lui aveva lasciato l'album su una panchina, scaldai la
>   ***collamidina*** con un fiammifero e staccai Ghigghia della Roma, che era una figurina rarissima, non l'aveva nessuno.

[Qui](http://www.ebay.it/itm/BARATTOLO-COLLAMIDINA-LONGO-COLUMBIA-NASTRI-FARINA-MAMMA-DEPOCA-/161807405758) puoi vedere la sua confezione caratteristica del tempo

Comment: E si doveva scaldare per poterla usare?

Comment: A quanto ho capito era sensibile al calore che la rendeva liquida e quindi utilizzabile in maniera più facile.

Comment: Poi la coccoina ebbe il sopravvento

Comment: Esatto, sempre con lo stesso odore di mandorla....